Why do my flutter app crashes when I click on suggested fill-in emails for authentication log in?
I am testing my app in debug mode and during authentication of app, it gives me suggested emails (the ones that I have used earlier). But when I click on them, the app crashes suddenly. Why would this happen? But If I type in the entire email and password using keyboard there are no issues. Any fix for this?
I use firebase for authentication.
